# Ken Buck, R Colorado's 4th district resigns today?

Tags: united-states, congress

How does Congressmen Ken Buck's impromptu resignation this afternoon affect/threaten the Republican's Majority in the U.S. Congress?

Comment: If it's only once congressmen it would probably shorten but not eliminate the majority which was on the order of 6-7 representatives I think. In which threat are you specifically interested in?

Answer (score 5):

It [reduces the majority](https://pressgallery.house.gov/member-data/party-breakdown) to (currently) 5, which means Republicans can only have up to 2 defectors on party line votes. Democrats are expected to pick a seat in a [special election in New York next month](https://www.vote.nyc/elections), reducing the Republican majority further to 4.

From the comment by [Kevin Sherlock](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/48526/kelvin-sherlock):

> Colorado is holding the special election to replace Buck on June 25th. Given that it's a safe Republican district (and current 3rd district's rep Lauren Boebert won't be running, which could then vacate her seat), team elephant will be back to +5 by July

Republicans are expected to pick a seat in November to fill the vacancy after McCarthy's resignation, bringing it back to 6 for a short period until the next congress, allowing up to 3 defections on party line votes.

Comment: Colorado is holding the special election to replace Buck on June 25th. Given that it's a safe Republican district (and current 3rd district's rep Lauren Boebert won't be running, which could then vacate her seat), team elephant will be back to +5 by July.